# Show static content with parameters with Spray

Tags: scala, spray, static-content

I'm trying to serve an HTML page using Spray. It's fairly easy using `getFromResource` and `getFromResourceDirectory`, but I additionally need to pass some query parameters so that some Javascript on the page knows what to do. Is that possible ? All my prior attempts consisted in this kind of things

```
val route = path("show-repo") { serveResourceWithParams(SHOW_REPO) } ~ getFromResourceDirectory("web")
def serveWithParams(page: String, params: (String, String)*) = {
    val url = page + (if (params.isEmpty) "" else "?") + params.map { case (k, v) => s"$k=$v" }.mkString("&") 
    getFromResource(url)
}
```

but I now realize it was a bit naive

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new case class with members of type `Array[Byte]` and `List[(String, String)]`.

```
case class FileWithParams(file: Array[Byte], params: List[(String, String)])
```

If you know the file won't be huge, you can read it in one shot with

```
FileUtils.readAllBytes
```

Assuming you're using(which you need to run Spray) https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/blob/master/parboiled-core/src/main/java/org/parboiled/common/FileUtils.java

Then manually read the file contents, create the case class, and marshall it as you would normally do.

Of course, my preferred way would be to split this up into two async requests and wait for both to complete. You'll probably be waiting on the file route to complete anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I'm not sure I get it though. When you say *marshall as you would normally do*, are you talking about serializing to Json, because this is what the rest of my service does ? The response has to be valid HTML in this case. I also don't get your point on separate async requests. Separate requests for what ? The file from one side and what on the other side ? In my case the parameters are a mere parameter list that can be returned immediately, no need to process anything. Thanks ir advance for clarifying :p

Comment: I was basically trying to parse a path such as `git-stats/[owner]/[repo]/[operation]` to return `git-stats/someHtmlFile.html?repo=[owner]/[repo]`. Instead of doing this, I now directly call my Spray service using a query string, and the parameters just get passed over, the JS on the returned page can read it just fine